# Refresh local cache with multiple users making changes to a database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5

I am going to get data from the database once and load into a cache, then query that in-memory cache.  There will be inserts/updates/deletes by multiple users, so is there a way I can reload the cache if this happens?

I was thinking I would query the db and check for a last updated field and also check the count and if any of those differ from what is in my cache, I would reload data into the cache. Is this a good solution or is there another way of handling this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) as your cache. You can then [add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138343.aspx) items to your cache with a CacheItemPolicy with [SqlChangeMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.sqlchangemonitor.aspx)

**EDIT**: If you are using .NET 3.5 you can still use [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) get get notification of database changes and then refresh your cache when you get notifications.

Comment: I updated my tag.  Unfortunately, this looks like it is only for 4.0+. I am using 3.5